# NAS Parallel Benchmarks MPI Segmentation Fault executing FT and MG for class D

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, mpi, benchmarking, gfortran

I'm trying to run 5 kernels (CG, EP, FT, IS, MG) of NAS Parallel Benchmarks 3.4.2 on various platforms (AMD, Intel and ARM).
I'd like to execute all 5 algorithms in MPI implementation with np=[1,2,4,8,16,32,64] (number of processes). CG and EP execute correctly for all np values.
Problem I'm facing is that class D - FT (Fourier Transform) and MG (Multi Grid) algoritms throw a segmentation error for np<=8 (number of processes). This does not happen for the lower classes (S, W, A, B, C), whereas IS (Integer Sort) returns an informative message saying that for class D process number is within range (4-1024) - which is something I'd expect from the other two programs.

Configuration used to compile the project is based on provided templates "make.def.template" for Intel and AMD, and "make.def.gcc_mpich_m" for ARM based AMPERE. Code I'm executing is not modified in any manner, donwloaded and compiled from https://www.nas.nasa.gov/software/npb.html .

Providing outputs for np=1

- FT - MPI, class D, np=1

> Can be successfully executed with n >= 2, but not n=1.
> [Problem sizes](https://www.nas.nasa.gov/software/npb_problem_sizes.html)

```
mpirun --use-hwthread-cpus -n 1 ./NPB3.4.2/NPB3.4-MPI/bin/ft.D.x
```

```
 NAS Parallel Benchmarks 3.4 -- FT Benchmark

 No input file inputft.data. Using compiled defaults
 Size                : 2048x1024x1024  (class D)
 Iterations          :             25
 Number of processes :              1
 Processor array     :         1x   1
 Layout type         :             0D

Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x7f7e41206d21 in ???
#1  0x7f7e41205ef5 in ???
#2  0x7f7e40ea420f in ???
#3  0x556771bb530a in compute_indexmap_
        at /home/ozm/c_projects/NAS-Parallel-Benchmarks/NPB3.4.2/NPB3.4-MPI/FT/ft.f90:694
#4  0x556771bb9eae in ft
        at /home/ozm/c_projects/NAS-Parallel-Benchmarks/NPB3.4.2/NPB3.4-MPI/FT/ft.f90:111
#5  0x556771bb32ae in main
        at /home/ozm/c_projects/NAS-Parallel-Benchmarks/NPB3.4.2/NPB3.4-MPI/FT/ft.f90:84
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned
a non-zero exit code. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun noticed that process rank 0 with PID 0 on node ozmpc2 exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault).
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**ft.90:694**

```
         do i = 1,dims(2,3)
            ii =  mod(i+xstart(3)-2+nx/2, nx) - nx/2
            ii2 = ii*ii
            do j = 1,dims(3,3)
               jj = mod(j+ystart(3)-2+ny/2, ny) - ny/2
               ij2 = jj*jj+ii2
               do k = 1,dims(1,3)
                  kk = mod(k+zstart(3)-2+nz/2, nz) - nz/2
--->              twiddle(k,i,j) = dexp(ap*dfloat(kk*kk+ij2))
               end do
            end do
         end do
```

Found a comment regarding the functionality of "twiddle"

> TO REDUCE THE AMOUNT OF MEMORY REQUIRED BY THE BENCHMARK WE NO LONGER STORE THE ENTIRE TIME EVOLUTION ARRAY "EX" FOR ALL TIME STEPS, BUT JUST FOR THE FIRST. ALSO, IT IS STORED ONLY FOR THE PART OF THE GRID FOR WHICH THE CALLING PROCESSOR IS RESPONSIBLE, SO THAT THE MEMORY USAGE BECOMES SCALABLE. THIS NEW ARRAY IS CALLED "TWIDDLE" (SEE NPB3.0-SER).
> TO AVOID PROBLEMS WITH VERY LARGE ARRAY SIZES THAT ARE COMPUTED BY MULTIPLYING GRID DIMENSIONS (CAUSING INTEGER OVERFLOW IN THE VARIABLE NTOTAL) AND SUBSEQUENTLY DIVIDING BY THE NUMBER OF PROCESSORS, WE COMPUTE THE SIZE OF ARRAY PARTITIONS MORE CONSERVATIVELY AS ((NX*NY)/NP)*NZ, WHERE NX, NY, AND NZ ARE GRID DIMENSIONS AND NP IS THE NUMBER OF PROCESSORS, THE RESULT IS STORED IN "NTDIVNP". FOR THE PERFORMANCE CALCULATION WE STORE THE TOTAL NUMBER OF GRID POINTS IN A FLOATING POINT NUMBER "NTOTAL_F" INSTEAD OF AN INTEGER. THIS FIX WILL FAIL IF THE NUMBER OF PROCESSORS IS SMALL.

- MG - MPI, class D, np=1

> Can be successfully executed with n >= 8, but not n=[1,2,4].

```
mpirun --use-hwthread-cpus -n 1 ./NPB3.4.2/NPB3.4-MPI/bin/mg.D.x
```

```
 NAS Parallel Benchmarks 3.4 -- MG Benchmark

 No input file. Using compiled defaults 

Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x7f07fe12fd21 in ???
#1  0x7f07fe12eef5 in ???
#2  0x7f07fddf920f in ???
#3  0x7f07fdf41b58 in ???
#4  0x556711256740 in zero3_
        at /home/ozm/c_projects/NAS-Parallel-Benchmarks/NPB3.4.2/NPB3.4-MPI/MG/mg.f90:2566
#5  0x556711262b8c in mg_mpi
        at /home/ozm/c_projects/NAS-Parallel-Benchmarks/NPB3.4.2/NPB3.4-MPI/MG/mg.f90:230
#6  0x5567112562fe in main
        at /home/ozm/c_projects/NAS-Parallel-Benchmarks/NPB3.4.2/NPB3.4-MPI/MG/mg.f90:52
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned
a non-zero exit code. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun noticed that process rank 0 with PID 0 on node ozmpc2 exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault).
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**mg.f90:2566**

```
!---------------------------------------------------------------------
!---------------------------------------------------------------------
      subroutine zero3(z,n1,n2,n3)
!---------------------------------------------------------------------
!---------------------------------------------------------------------

      use mpinpb
      implicit none

      integer n1, n2, n3
      double precision z(n1,n2,n3)
      integer i1, i2, i3

      do  i3=1,n3
--->     do  i2=1,n2
            do  i1=1,n1
               z(i1,i2,i3)=0.0D0
            enddo
         enddo
      enddo

      return
      end
```

I'm not sure whether its an expected behaviour for FT and MG algorithms, if not, what would be a possible solution to successfully execute these algorithms for np=[1,2,4].
Github link with the project and execution logs can be found here: https://github.com/victorconka/NAS-Parallel-Benchmarks.

## Compiler information

### gcc

```
ozm@ozmpc2:~/c_projects/NAS-Parallel-Benchmarks$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:hsa
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-9/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,gm2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-9 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none=/build/gcc-9-HskZEa/gcc-9-9.3.0/debian/tmp-nvptx/usr,hsa --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)
```

### mpif90

```
ozm@ozmpc2:~/c_projects/NAS-Parallel-Benchmarks$ mpif90 -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/usr/bin/gfortran
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:hsa
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-9/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,gm2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-9 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none=/build/gcc-9-HskZEa/gcc-9-9.3.0/debian/tmp-nvptx/usr,hsa --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)
```

### make.def

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
#                SITE- AND/OR PLATFORM-SPECIFIC DEFINITIONS. 
#
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Items in this file will need to be changed for each platform.
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Parallel Fortran:
#
# For CG, EP, FT, MG, LU, SP and BT, which are in Fortran, the following must 
# be defined:
#
# MPIFC      - Fortran compiler
# FFLAGS     - Fortran compilation arguments
# FMPI_INC   - any -I arguments required for compiling MPI/Fortran 
# FLINK      - Fortran linker
# FLINKFLAGS - Fortran linker arguments
# FMPI_LIB   - any -L and -l arguments required for linking MPI/Fortran 
# 
# compilations are done with $(MPIFC) $(FMPI_INC) $(FFLAGS) or
#                            $(MPIFC) $(FFLAGS)
# linking is done with       $(FLINK) $(FMPI_LIB) $(FLINKFLAGS)
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# This is the fortran compiler used for MPI programs
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MPIFC = mpif90
# This links MPI fortran programs; usually the same as ${MPIFC}
FLINK   = $(MPIFC)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# These macros are passed to the linker to help link with MPI correctly
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FMPI_LIB =

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# These macros are passed to the compiler to help find 'mpif.h'
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FMPI_INC =

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Global *compile time* flags for Fortran programs
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FFLAGS  = -O3 -g

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Global *link time* flags. Flags for increasing maximum executable 
# size usually go here. 
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FLINKFLAGS = $(FFLAGS)


#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Parallel C:
#
# For IS, which is in C, the following must be defined:
#
# MPICC      - C compiler 
# CFLAGS     - C compilation arguments
# CMPI_INC   - any -I arguments required for compiling MPI/C 
# CLINK      - C linker
# CLINKFLAGS - C linker flags
# CMPI_LIB   - any -L and -l arguments required for linking MPI/C 
#
# compilations are done with $(MPICC) $(CMPI_INC) $(CFLAGS) or
#                            $(MPICC) $(CFLAGS)
# linking is done with       $(CLINK) $(CMPI_LIB) $(CLINKFLAGS)
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# This is the C compiler used for MPI programs
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MPICC = mpicc
# This links MPI C programs; usually the same as ${MPICC}
CLINK   = $(MPICC)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# These macros are passed to the linker to help link with MPI correctly
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CMPI_LIB =

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# These macros are passed to the compiler to help find 'mpi.h'
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CMPI_INC =

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Global *compile time* flags for C programs
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CFLAGS  = -O3 -g

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Global *link time* flags. Flags for increasing maximum executable 
# size usually go here. 
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CLINKFLAGS = $(CFLAGS)


#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# MPI dummy library:
#
# Uncomment if you want to use the MPI dummy library supplied by NAS instead 
# of the true message-passing library. The include file redefines several of
# the above macros. It also invokes make in subdirectory MPI_dummy. Make 
# sure that no spaces or tabs precede include.
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# include ../config/make.dummy


#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Utilities C:
#
# This is the C compiler used to compile C utilities.  Flags required by 
# this compiler go here also; typically there are few flags required; hence 
# there are no separate macros provided for such flags.
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CC  = gcc -g


#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Destination of executables, relative to subdirs of the main directory. . 
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
BINDIR  = ../bin


#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Some machines (e.g. Crays) have 128-bit DOUBLE PRECISION numbers, which
# is twice the precision required for the NPB suite. A compiler flag 
# (e.g. -dp) can usually be used to change DOUBLE PRECISION variables to
# 64 bits, but the MPI library may continue to send 128 bits. Short of
# recompiling MPI, the solution is to use MPI_REAL to send these 64-bit
# numbers, and MPI_COMPLEX to send their complex counterparts. Uncomment
# the following line to enable this substitution. 
# 
# NOTE: IF THE I/O BENCHMARK IS BEING BUILT, WE USE CONVERTFLAG TO
#       SPECIFIY THE FORTRAN RECORD LENGTH UNIT. IT IS A SYSTEM-SPECIFIC
#       VALUE (USUALLY 1 OR 4). UNCOMMENT THE SECOND LINE AND SUBSTITUTE
#       THE CORRECT VALUE FOR "length".
#       IF BOTH 128-BIT DOUBLE PRECISION NUMBERS AND I/O ARE TO BE ENABLED,
#       UNCOMMENT THE THIRD LINE AND SUBSTITUTE THE CORRECT VALUE FOR
#       "length"
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CONVERTFLAG   = -DCONVERTDOUBLE
# CONVERTFLAG   = -DFORTRAN_REC_SIZE=length
# CONVERTFLAG   = -DCONVERTDOUBLE -DFORTRAN_REC_SIZE=length
CONVERTFLAG = -DFORTRAN_REC_SIZE=0


#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# The variable RAND controls which random number generator 
# is used. It is described in detail in README.install. 
# Use "randi8" unless there is a reason to use another one. 
# Other allowed values are "randi8_safe", "randdp" and "randdpvec"
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RAND   = randi8
# The following is highly reliable but may be slow:
# RAND   = randdp
```

### suite.def

```
# config/suite.def
# This file is used to build several benchmarks with a single command. 
# Typing "make suite" in the main directory will build all the benchmarks
# specified in this file. 
# Each line of this file contains a benchmark name, class, and number
# of nodes. The name is one of "cg", "is", "ep", mg", "ft", "sp", "bt", 
# "lu", and "dt". 
# The class is one of "S", "W", "A", "B", "C", "D", and "E"
# (except that no classes C, D and E for DT, and no class E for IS).
# The number of nodes must be a legal number for a particular
# benchmark. The utility which parses this file is primitive, so
# formatting is inflexible. Separate name/class by tabs. 
# Comments start with "#" as the first character on a line. 
# No blank lines. 
# The following example builds sample sizes of all benchmarks. 
ep  D
cg  D
mg  D
ft  D
is  D
```

### Compilation command

```
make suite
```

### Compilation output

```
ozm@ozmpc2:~/c_projects/NAS-Parallel-Benchmarks/NPB3.4.2/NPB3.4-MPI$ make suite
make[1]: se entra en el directorio '/home/ozm/c_projects/NAS-Parallel-Benchmarks/NPB3.4.2/NPB3.4-MPI/EP'
rm -f *.o *~ *.mod
rm -f npbparams.h core
make[1]: se sale del directorio '/home/ozm/c_projects/NAS-Parallel-Benchmarks/NPB3.4.2/NPB3.4-MPI/EP'
make[1]: se entra en el directorio '/home/ozm/c_projects/NAS-Parallel-Benchmarks/NPB3.4.2/NPB3.4-MPI/EP'
make[2]: se entra en el directorio '/home/ozm/c_projects/NAS-Parallel-Benchmarks/NPB3.4.2/NPB3.4-MPI/sys'
make[2]: No se hace nada para 'all'.
make[2]: se sale del directorio '/home/ozm/c_projects/NAS-Parallel-Benchmarks/NPB3.4.2/NPB3.4-MPI/sys'
../sys/setparams ep D 
mpif90 -c -I/usr/local/include -O3 -g -fcheck=all ep_data.f90
mpif90 -c -I/usr/local/include -O3 -g -fcheck=all mpinpb.f90
mpif90 -c -I/usr/local/include -O3 -g -fcheck=all ep.f90
mpif90 -c -I/usr/local/include -O3 -g -fcheck=all verify.f90
mpif90 -O3 -g -fcheck=all -o ../bin/ep.D.x ep.o ep_data.o verify.o mpinpb.o ../common/print_results.o ../common/randi8.o ../common/timers.o -L/usr/local/lib -lmpi
make[1]: se sale del directorio '/home/ozm/c_projects/NAS-Parallel-Benchmarks/NPB3.4.2/NPB3.4-MPI/EP'
make[1]: se entra en el directorio '/home/ozm/c_projects/NAS-Parallel-Benchmarks/NPB3.4.2/NPB3.4-MPI/CG'
rm -f *.o *.mod *~ 
rm -f npbparams.h core
make[1]: se sale del directorio '/home/ozm/c_projects/NAS-Parallel-Benchmarks/NPB3.4.2/NPB3.4-MPI/CG'
make[1]: se entra en el directorio '/home/ozm/c_projects/NAS-Parallel-Benchmarks/NPB3.4.2/NPB3.4-MPI/CG'
make[2]: se entra en el directorio '/home/ozm/c_projects/NAS-Parallel-Benchmarks/NPB3.4.2/NPB3.4-MPI/sys'
make[2]: No se hace nada para 'all'.
make[2]: se sale del directorio '/home/ozm/c_projects/NAS-Parallel-Benchmarks/NPB3.4.2/NPB3.4-MPI/sys'
../sys/setparams cg D 
mpif90 -c -I/usr/local/include -O3 -g -fcheck=all mpinpb.f90
mpif90 -c -I/usr/local/include -O3 -g -fcheck=all cg_data.f90
mpif90 -c -I/usr/local/include -O3 -g -fcheck=all cg.f90
mpif90 -O3 -g -fcheck=all -o ../bin/cg.D.x cg.o cg_data.o mpinpb.o ../common/print_results.o ../common/get_active_nprocs.o ../common/randi8.o ../common/timers.o -L/usr/local/lib -lmpi
make[1]: se sale del directorio '/home/ozm/c_projects/NAS-Parallel-Benchmarks/NPB3.4.2/NPB3.4-MPI/CG'
make[1]: se entra en el directorio '/home/ozm/c_projects/NAS-Parallel-Benchmarks/NPB3.4.2/NPB3.4-MPI/MG'
rm -f *.o *.mod *~ 
rm -f npbparams.h core
make[1]: se sale del directorio '/home/ozm/c_projects/NAS-Parallel-Benchmarks/NPB3.4.2/NPB3.4-MPI/MG'
make[1]: se entra en el directorio '/home/ozm/c_projects/NAS-Parallel-Benchmarks/NPB3.4.2/NPB3.4-MPI/MG'
make[2]: se entra en el directorio '/home/ozm/c_projects/NAS-Parallel-Benchmarks/NPB3.4.2/NPB3.4-MPI/sys'
make[2]: No se hace nada para 'all'.
make[2]: se sale del directorio '/home/ozm/c_projects/NAS-Parallel-Benchmarks/NPB3.4.2/NPB3.4-MPI/sys'
../sys/setparams mg D 
mpif90 -c -I/usr/local/include -O3 -g -fcheck=all mpinpb.f90
mpif90 -c -I/usr/local/include -O3 -g -fcheck=all mg_data.f90
mpif90 -c -I/usr/local/include -O3 -g -fcheck=all mg.f90
mpif90 -O3 -g -fcheck=all -o ../bin/mg.D.x mg.o mg_data.o mpinpb.o ../common/print_results.o ../common/get_active_nprocs.o ../common/randi8.o ../common/timers.o -L/usr/local/lib -lmpi
make[1]: se sale del directorio '/home/ozm/c_projects/NAS-Parallel-Benchmarks/NPB3.4.2/NPB3.4-MPI/MG'
make[1]: se entra en el directorio '/home/ozm/c_projects/NAS-Parallel-Benchmarks/NPB3.4.2/NPB3.4-MPI/FT'
rm -f *.o *.mod *~ mputil*
rm -f ft npbparams.h core
make[1]: se sale del directorio '/home/ozm/c_projects/NAS-Parallel-Benchmarks/NPB3.4.2/NPB3.4-MPI/FT'
make[1]: se entra en el directorio '/home/ozm/c_projects/NAS-Parallel-Benchmarks/NPB3.4.2/NPB3.4-MPI/FT'
make[2]: se entra en el directorio '/home/ozm/c_projects/NAS-Parallel-Benchmarks/NPB3.4.2/NPB3.4-MPI/sys'
make[2]: No se hace nada para 'all'.
make[2]: se sale del directorio '/home/ozm/c_projects/NAS-Parallel-Benchmarks/NPB3.4.2/NPB3.4-MPI/sys'
../sys/setparams ft D 
mpif90 -c -I/usr/local/include -O3 -g -fcheck=all mpinpb.f90
mpif90 -c -I/usr/local/include -O3 -g -fcheck=all ft_data.f90
mpif90 -c -I/usr/local/include -O3 -g -fcheck=all ft.f90
mpif90 -O3 -g -fcheck=all -o ../bin/ft.D.x ft.o ft_data.o mpinpb.o ../common/get_active_nprocs.o ../common/randi8.o ../common/print_results.o ../common/timers.o -L/usr/local/lib -lmpi
make[1]: se sale del directorio '/home/ozm/c_projects/NAS-Parallel-Benchmarks/NPB3.4.2/NPB3.4-MPI/FT'
make[1]: se entra en el directorio '/home/ozm/c_projects/NAS-Parallel-Benchmarks/NPB3.4.2/NPB3.4-MPI/IS'
rm -f *.o *~ mputil*
rm -f is npbparams.h core
make[1]: se sale del directorio '/home/ozm/c_projects/NAS-Parallel-Benchmarks/NPB3.4.2/NPB3.4-MPI/IS'
make[1]: se entra en el directorio '/home/ozm/c_projects/NAS-Parallel-Benchmarks/NPB3.4.2/NPB3.4-MPI/IS'
make[2]: se entra en el directorio '/home/ozm/c_projects/NAS-Parallel-Benchmarks/NPB3.4.2/NPB3.4-MPI/sys'
make[2]: No se hace nada para 'all'.
make[2]: se sale del directorio '/home/ozm/c_projects/NAS-Parallel-Benchmarks/NPB3.4.2/NPB3.4-MPI/sys'
../sys/setparams is D 
mpicc -c  -O3 -g -fcheck=all is.c
cc1: warning: command line option ‘-fcheck=all’ is valid for Fortran but not for C
mpicc -O3 -g -fcheck=all -o ../bin/is.D.x is.o ../common/c_print_results.o ../common/c_timers.o -L/usr/local/lib -lmpi
make[1]: se sale del directorio '/home/ozm/c_projects/NAS-Parallel-Benchmarks/NPB3.4.2/NPB3.4-MPI/IS'
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. If different benchmarks (i.e. different programs) crash, that is too broad for 1 question. Also the other programs that do not crash are rather unrelated to your problem and should not be included here. You should focus on one issue, i.e. one benchmark and show the related code here directly within your question (insert as formatted text), not as external link. Also you should try to strip down the code as far as possible to reproduce your crash.

Comment: Your stack trace is uninformative. Recompile the whole code with the `-g` option and show the actual stack trace.

Comment: Welcome, please take the welcome [tour]. I also suggest reading [ask]. You should never assume that code someone, even someone relatively well known, posted somewhere is correct and you just need to compile and run it in some other way and everything will be fine. Segmentation fault is a very serious error and may be caused by many issues: incorrect code, software incompatibilities (libraries, compilers). Therefore we need much more information. We need to know the location of the crash. Follow the `-g` flag recommendation. Try also the `-fcheck=all` flag. Try running with just one process...

Comment: ... Tell us the exact versions of your compiler and the MPI libraries. Tell us the exact commands the `make` command executed or at least the complete output of the `make` command. Do not hide this information in a github repository, it must be right here inside your question.

Comment: Thanks for your welcome messages. It is indeed my first post and I am pleasently surprised of what a great community this is. I've added `-g` and `-fcheck=all` parameters to make.def, also edited the post to include the resulting info.

Comment: Can you read a stack trace? `ft.f90:694` is the latest source line that causes the problem. What's on that line? If your program crashes on a single process, run in a debugger. Otherwise, `mpiexec -n 2 xterm -e gdb ft`.

Comment: The program crashes on the single process. Line `ft.f90:694` contains a reference to an array twiddle, which from what is said in the code comments, is the array containing the problem grid. From the provided formula in the same comment, size D grid 2048x1024x1024 matches 4 byte integer size, what is probably causing this error.